# How to maximize a browser window using the Python bindings for Selenium 2-WebDriver?

Tags: python, webdriver, selenium-webdriver

I wanted to know how to maximize a browser window using the Python bindings for Selenium 2-WebDriver.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[The trunk version](http://code.google.com/p/selenium/source/browse/trunk/py/selenium/) has `webdriver.set_window_position()`, `webdriver.set_window_size()` methods:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
import time
from contextlib import closing
from selenium.webdriver import Firefox # pip install selenium

with closing(Firefox()) as browser:
    browser.set_window_position(0, 0) #NOTE: 0,0 might fail on some systems
    browser.set_window_size(800, 600)
    time.sleep(2)
```

Answer (score 12):

You can use `browser.maximize_window()` for that

Answer (score 0):

The best way to do is using WebDriver object in python itself. I tried in my Mac machine and it worked super fine.

driver.fullscreen_window()

Once you create a webdriver object driver, you will be able to get this. Sharing a sample snippet below.

```
from selenium import webdriver
driver = webdriver.Chrome()
driver.fullscreen_window()
url = "https://github.com/sam4u3/Selenium_Screenshot/tree/master/test"
driver.get(url)
driver.quit()
```

Hope this helps! Cheers!