# 'window_maximize()' is not an attribute of WebDriver in Selenium

Tags: python, selenium, selenium-webdriver

I am using Selenium and for this task I need to maximize the browser after the page is loaded, the problem is that I am getting the following error and can't seem to understand how to solve it.

```
AttributeError: 'WebDriver' object has no attribute 'window_maximize'
```

Here is the code I am testing

```
from pyvirtualdisplay import Display
from ftplib import FTP
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.common.exceptions import TimeoutException
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait # available since 2.4.0
from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys

#initialize HIDDEN display
display = Display(visible=0, size=(1366, 768))
display.start()


browser = webdriver.Firefox()

browser.get('http://youtube.com/')
browser.window_maximize();
...
```

Isn't `window_maximize` an attribute of the `browser`?

I am using python and Selenium Server 2.28

Any tip much appreciated!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

OK, after much looking for how to use `window_maximize` I found out I can use `browser.set_window_size(800, 600)` instead.

I tested and it works fine. It is important to set the browser to `browser.set_window_position(0, 0)`

The answer was found here [How to maximize a browser window using the Python bindings for Selenium 2-WebDriver?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8075297/how-to-maximize-a-browser-window-using-the-python-bindings-for-selenium-2-webdri)

Answer (score 3):

You can use `browser.maximize_window()`. I think the problem was in the wrong function name.